# Problem with onMouseOut event with select box options (IE)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

The problem I am facing with below code is that whenever I try to select any option from the select box, the `mouseout` event executed (in IE, Mozilla doing great) and option disappear. How can one get over this bug?

```
<select name="ed" id="ed" dir="ltr"  style="width:200px;overflow:hidden;" onMouseOver="this.style.width='auto'" onMouseOut="this.style.width='200px';">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">click here</option>
      <option value="1">Samuel Jackson</option>
      <option value="2">David Nalog</option>
      <option value="3">This one is a real real big name</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: is option set to hidden or removed from the DOM?

Comment: The option is there only, but if the option having length more than 200px it won't show in IE using style="width:200px;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the code do it conditionally. Now it is working fine. Check it.

```
<select name="ed" id="ed" dir="ltr"  style="width:200px;overflow:hidden;" 
        OnMouseOver="this.style.width='auto';" onmouseout="if(!this.focussed) {this.style.width='200px';}"  onfocus="this.focussed=true;" onblur="this.style.width='200px';this.focussed=false;" >
      <option value="1" selected="selected">click here</option>
      <option value="1">Samuel Jackson</option>
      <option value="2">David Nalog</option>
      <option value="3">This one is a real real big name</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: onBlur will not work untill it get focus, the problem arise when you just scroll the mouse over the select box.

Comment: Look at it now. I have taken care of that problem.

Comment: great buddy!! I just append onChange="this.style.width='200px';"
Thanx a Gallon